# Android : Adding tabs below the action bar

Tags: java, android, tabs

In my Android application I have implemented a tab layout with swipeable views by following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) tutorial. It works fine. But I want to add these tabs below the action bar.

Can anyone please be so kind enough to explain how I can do this?

Comment: So are you trying to add new tabs, or add the tab titles below the action bar?

Comment: try this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Comment: @KDEx What I want is to add tab titles below the actiob bar.

Comment: I think you should check you app theme
Use Holo light with dark action bar 
Actionbar auto arrives

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-action-bar-with-tab.html

Try this ^_^ maybe this tut helps you a lot :D

Comment: While the link may answer the question, it is necessary to post the essential parts of the answer here also. Doing so would make sure that your answer remains valid even if the link becomes inactive. Please consider adding more details :)

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the link you post there is a download button. I advise to download the full project and inspect/run the code.

To add the titles below the action bar the key section of the code is to have the following in your `FragmentActivity`

```
// Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this : [Tabs Below ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)

Above is the officical android developers link that will explain you to add the tabs below the ActionBar from scratch

Comment: It has nothing to do with Tabs below ActionBar